# Can I Use My OpenSSL CA to Sign My OpenVPN Certificates?

Tags: openvpn, certificate, openssl, rsa, trusted-root-certificates

I'm not sure if it sounds like a stupid question but all the guides I've looked at when it comes to making certificates for OpenVPN all use Easy-RSA.

Some of my servers such as my NAS, and OpenMediaVault server on my home LAN use SSL to encrypt the data, therefore I have created my own CA (certificate of authority) that is installed to each client. Having a single CA certificate installed automatically approves any of the certificates that are used on my servers saving installing multiple certificates on the client.

In regards to OpenVPN, I would rather skip making a second root certificate for OpenVPN and instead utilise the existing trusted root certificate I have made with OpenSSL already installed on my clients.

Is this possible?

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

Would the generation of the diffie hellman be the equivalent of the `openssl req x509` command?

This is the first command I use when creating my OpenSSL certificates

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout ca/cakey.pem -out ca/cacert.pem -days 3650 -sha256 -nodes -config configs/ca_openssl.cnf
```

I'm just trying to find out the equivalent commends to the easy-RSA

Comment: Is it possible, there shouldn't be any reason, you can't do what you want.  If it's the best method, or the most secure, that entirely a subjective determination.  Have you tried to do this and run into an error?

Comment: "Would the generation of the Diffie-Hellman be the equivalent of the openssl req x509 command?"- You are aware of the fact that you should not use Diffie-Hellman to generate any certificate, right?  There is a known vulnerability.

Comment: Usually certificate creation doesn't involve DH _at all_ – the DH parameters are completely independent of the cert type. (Although there are DH-based certificates, nobody ever uses them, and shouldn't.)

Answer (score 0):

All guides use Easy-RSA because it's easy and it comes as *part of OpenVPN.*

Beyond that, however, OpenVPN uses completely standard RSA-based X.509 certificates, exactly like those used by HTTPS and other TLS. (The OpenVPN control channel even uses regular TLS, although within a custom multiplexing layer.)

The only important difference is that older OpenVPN versions used to be more strict about extended­Key­Usage than other TLS clients; for example if you used `--remote-cert-tls client` it would require the certificate to have *only* "TLS client" usage and would reject certificates which had server&client usage OIDs set (as is common for most TLS certificates).

Finally, OpenVPN clients don't require the CA certificate to be installed system-wide and in fact the authors discourage it somewhat. The CA certificate can just be included inline in the configuration file.